# Regex pattern for illegal regex groups `\g<...>`

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

In the following regex `r"\g<NAME>\w+"`, I would like to know that a group named `NAME` must be used for replacements corresponding to a match.

**Which regex matches the wrong use of `\g<...>` ?**

For example, the following code finds any not escaped groups.

```
p = re.compile(r"(?:[^\\])\\g<(\w+)>")

for m in p.finditer(r"\g<NAME>\w+\\g<ESCAPED>"):
    print(m.group(1))
```

But there is a last problem to solve. How can I manage cases of `\g<WRONGUSE\>` and`\g\<WRONGUSE>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, I have this solution.

```
# Good uses.
p = re.compile(r"(?:[^\\])\\g<(\w+)>")

for m in p.finditer(r"</\g\<at__tribut1>\\g<notattribut>>"):
    print(m.group(1))

# Bad uses.
p = re.compile(r"(?:[^\\])\\g(?!<\w+>)")

if p.search(r"</\g\<at__tribut1>\\g<notattribut>>"):
    print("Wrong use !")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the only restriction on named capture groups is that you can't put metacharacters in there, such as `.` `\`, etc...

Have you come across some kind of problem with named capture groups?

The regex you used, `r"illegal|(\g<NAME>\w+)"` is only illegal because you referred to a backreference without it being declared earlier in the regex string. If you want to make a named capture group, it is `(?P<NAME>regex)`

Like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "sup bro"
>>> re.sub(r"(?P<greeting>sup) bro", r"\g<greeting> mate", string)
'sup mate'
```

---

If you wanted to do some kind of analysis on the actual regex string in use, I don't think there is anything inside the `re` module which can do this natively.

You would need to run another match on the string itself, so, you would put the regex into a string variable and then match something like `\(\?P<(.*?)>\)` which would give you the named capture group's name.

I hope that is what you are asking for... Let me  know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I know how to replace the group in a legalregex but my problem is to analyze the pattern rather than to use it. I will update my question.

Comment: I've changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want is to get the string of the group name, right?

Maybe you can get it by doing this:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"illegal|(?P<group_name>\w+)")
>>> regex.groupindex
{'group_name': 1}
```

As you see, [`groupindex`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.regex.groupindex) returns a dictionary mapping the group names and their position in the regex. Having that, it is easy to retrieve the string:

```
>>> # A list of the group names in your regex:
... regex.groupindex.keys()
['group_name']

>>> # The string of your group name:
... regex.groupindex.keys()[0]
'group_name'
```

Don't know if that is what you were looking for...

Comment: Thanks for pointing but I'm looking fro something different. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead?

```
\\g(?!<\w+>)
```

This search for any `g` *not* followed by `<…>`, thus a "wrong use".

Comment: Thanks, I can produce a solution thanks to your advice.